# How can I remove all filters in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to write a script that removes all filters in a spreadsheet once a day.

I haven't been able to find any good documentation on how to handle filtering in Google Apps Script.

<sub>I'd also be open to doing this using the Python API if it was possible that way.</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### This answer is outdated, please see @Davide's answer

---

**It IS possible**, with a little "cheating" :)

(Updated answer: there is a new Google service that allows it, see number 2)

---

**1 - Easy way**

Well, I managed to do it this way:

```js
var row = 1 //the row with filter 
var rowBefore = row 

//insert a row before the filters
Sheet.insertRowBefore(row);
row++; 

//move the filter row to the new row (this will move only content)
var Line = Sheet.getRange(row + ":" + row); 
Line.moveTo(Sheet.getRange(rowBefore + ":" + rowBefore)); 

//delete the old row, which contains the filters - this clears the filters      
Sheet.deleteRow(row); 

//if the row was frozen before deletion, freeze the new row    
Sheet.setFrozenRows(rowBefore);
```

---

**2 - Using the Sheets service:**

(Copied from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753410, comment #172)

```
function clearFilter() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ssId = ss.getId();
    var sheetId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
    var requests = [{
        "clearBasicFilter": {
        "sheetId": sheetId
        }
    }];
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, ssId);
}
```

(Copied from @AndreLung's comment below)

> Go to Resources, then "Advanced Google Services", locate "Google Sheets API and enable. also, go to [console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard) and enable "Sheets API"

---

**3 - Hard way:** (kept it here because I wrote it before thinking a little more)

1 - Remove first line (or line where filter buttons are)

```
Sheet.deleteRow(1);
```

2 - Insert it again :)

```
Sheet.insertRowBefore(1);
```

3 - Set its headers

```
Sheet.getRange("A1").setValue("Hi there");
Sheet.getRange("B1").setValue("Here I am Again with no filter");

//alternatively
var LineVals = Sheet.getRange("1:1").getValues(); 
LineVals[0][0] = "Hi there";
LineVals[0][1] = "Here I am again";
LineVals[0][2] = "With no filters";
Sheet.getRange("1:1").setValues(LineVals);
//getValues is meant to keep the array exactly the size of the row
```

4 - Set the line color again:

```
//Cell color                                   
Sheet.getRange("1:1").setBackground('#ff3300');
```

5 - Set font styles:

```
 //I didn't test these ones....
 Sheet.getRange("1:1").setFontColor....
 Sheet.getRange("1:1").setFontFamily....     
 Sheet.getRange("1:1").setFontSize....
 //Actually there are a lot of font options available....
```

6 - If it was frozen before, freeze it again:

```
Sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
```

7 - And finally, if they had `NamedRanges`, consider naming the entire column instead of a single cell, that will preserve your names unharmed.

Comment: A little help for option 2:
go to Resources, then "Advanced Google Services", locate "Google Sheets API and enable.
also, go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard and enable "Sheets API"

Comment: Even easier now with ".getFilter()" and ".remove()".
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter

Answer (score 27):

There is a new super-easy possibility which I discovered by using the record macro function:

```
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
```

NB the "easy way" described before is not working anymore since moveTo now moves also the filters

Comment: you can also do this per sheet. 
```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ToEmail1");
sheet.getFilter().remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Since I wrote this answer way back in 2014, The tracked issue in the link has since been resolved with new methods to manipulate filters. My answer is now obsolete, but I keep getting downvotes for it so.... thanks. I'm aware, but leaving the initial answer for posterity.

I don't believe it's possible to manipulate the filters in Google Sheets programmatically. You can find an open issue for this [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=524). Star it to register your interest, but in the meantime I don't believe there's a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel, thank you very very much :-)

This is my implementation:

```
function delFVws_test(){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

    delFVws(sh, 1); 
}

function delFVws(sh, row){

    var rowp = row;
    sh.insertRowBefore(row++);   
    sh.getRange(row + ':' + row).copyTo(sh.getRange(rowp + ':' + rowp));
    sh.deleteRow(row); 
}
```

Preserves frozen lines and using copyTo instead of moveTo ensures not to *move the filters* from line to line.

Comment: By the way, this removes filters **and** stored _filter views_ as well (my original goal)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread, but for those that ran into this while searching google for an answer, the following code will remove all filters

```
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
```

Or to check if the sheet has a filter

```
if (!SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getFilter()) {  //returns null if fitler does not exist
    <what to do if there is no filter>
}
else {
    <what to do if there is a filter>
}
```

Comment: Any difference or distinction you want to make between this other answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50574261/9337071

Answer (score 0):

### Code based filter

This adds a filter using code, but it is not the same one that you add with a menu. You could add your own filter menu, that way you have control. [Google App Script / Spreadsheet - How to get filter criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645180/google-app-script-spreadsheet-how-to-get-filter-criteria)

### Menu based filter

As @HDCerberus says, there does not look to be a way to remove the "menu based filter".

### Python API

Python API is fine grain, but has very few features, so there is no way to even hide a row
never mind handle filters.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented Daniel's code

Changed moveTo to copyTo and used the options - Contents only.
Also removed frozen rows if any and added the shtRows.setFrozenRows(1) after my code was executed.

```
var shtRows = mySS.getSheetByName("Rows");
var row = 1 //the row with filter 
var rowBefore = row;
shtRows.setFrozenRows(0); // remove frozen
shtRows.insertRowBefore(row); //inserts a line before the filter
row++;
var Line = shtRows.getRange(row + ":" + row); //gets the filter line
Line.copyTo(shtRows.getRange(rowBefore + ":" + rowBefore), {contentsOnly:true}); //move to new line
shtRows.deleteRow(row); //deletes the filter line - this clears the filter

// a lot of code executing... and then ...
shtRows.setFrozenRows(rowBefore); //if row was frozen before, freeze it again
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
// 4. Clear any filters currently applied to this first sheet
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getFilter()
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#remove()
var currentFilter = sheet.getFilter();
if ( currentFilter !== null ) {
    console.log( 'a filter currently exists, clearing...' );
    sheet.getFilter().remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not using a removeColumnFilterCriteria Method,
lets say we have 2 columns... the code should by something like :

```
function _clearFilter(sheet,headers) {
  for (var i in headers){
    var filter = sheet.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(Number(i)+1);
  }
}

function clearFilter() {
  var NUM_COLUMNS = 2;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1,1,NUM_COLUMNS).getValues(); //or in better way to get the header columns
  _clearFilter(sheet,headers[0]);
}
```