# Google Scripts Error: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Must specify at least one request

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, jsonexception

I am trying to run a Google Script to delete unused filter views. I found the script on Stackoverflow

```
function delUnusedFilterViews() {

  var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Removing unnamed Filters from sheet: ' + sheetName);
  var allFilters = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId).sheets[0].filterViews;
  var filterArr =[];
  for (var i in allFilters) {
    var currFilter = allFilters[i];
    var filterName = currFilter.title;
    var currFilterId = currFilter.filterViewId;
    if (/Filter [0-9]/.test(filterName)) filterArr.push({ deleteFilterView: { filterId: currFilterId } })
  }
   Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
      requests: filterArr
    },
      ssId
    )
  Browser.msgBox("All Done. You need to reload the sheet to see the filters have been deleted");
}
```

I've never run a Google Script before, so I went through the process of adding in the "Sheets" services. However, I'm getting this error when I run it and I don't know what's going wrong:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to
> sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Must specify at
> least one request.

Comment: The problem is that you are calling batchUpdate before you are creating any request.  That's what batchUpdate needs because it's job is to process [requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request)

Comment: how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632698/mass-delete-filter-views-in-google-sheets

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved in a different post, but I will explain what the script does.

I tested the script and it works. There are a couple of things that you need to keep in mind when running the script.

1. This script will delete the **unnamed** filters. For example, from the list below, it will delete "Filter 1" and "Filter 2" because that's the default name it assigns when you don't specify a name for a new Filter view.

[image]

2. In this line `var allFilters = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId).sheets[0].filterViews;` you need to specify the sheet where you want to get the unnamed filters, count starts from `0`, so let's say for example you have unnamed filters in `Sheet2`, you have to change`sheets[0]` to `sheets[1]`.

[image]

3. If you don't have **unnamed** filters in the sheet that you specified in the line above, then it will fail and return the error that you're getting.