# How to Use UNIQUE() Function for Filtered Rows in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column in Google spreadsheet consist of names, and I already apply filter function in the header.So, I already able to choose filter option based on the name in the column.
 What I want to do is get value of cell that has been filtered without any duplication using UNIQUE() function but only for visible rows only.

```
+----------+----------+                              +---------+---------+
|   name  v|   Col2  v|   result table if i apply    |  name  v|  Col 2 v|
+----------+----------+ >> filter by name "John">>   +---------+---------+
| John     |    a     |                              | John    |    a    |
| andi     |    b     |                              | John    |    v    |
| John     |    v     |                              | John    |    d    |
| John     |    d     |                              | John    |    r    |  
| andi     |    f     |                              +---------+---------+
| John     |    r     |
+----------+----------+
```

If I use conventional UNIQUE() function to column 'name' of the filtered table, it will still show "John" and "andi" respectively, instead of only "John" showed up, because the hidden filtered rows of "andi" still being processed by UNIQUE() function. 
Please help me to make UNIQUE() function only process filtered rows, so the result will be only "JOHN". To put it simple, I want UNIQUE() has the ability as SUBTOTAL() which is only process/calculate the active or filtered cell/rows/range.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why not use FILTER function instead of FILTER view?

Answer (score 1):

Functions are applied to whole ranges, you may try filter data with function:

`=FILTER(A:B,A:A="John")`

or with `query`:

`=QUERY({A:B},"select 'John', Col2 where Col1 = 'John' label 'John' 'Name', Col2 'Col2'")`

And then apply `unique`:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:B,A:A="John"))`

Comment: thank you for your response @Max-makhrov. 

my fault i didn't explain that the condition of this table is already have Filter Function in the header. 
So, I already able to choose filter by Name "John" or "Andi". With this condition, I can't just put the string "John" into my formula, because I want it will be selected by choosing filter list in the top of the header table. 
Hmm, to put it simple, I want something similar to SUBTOTAL() function that only count VISIBLE rows that has been filtered, but has the ability of UNIQUE() function. 

Any idea??

Comment: The Q was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645180/google-app-script-spreadsheet-how-to-get-filter-criteria